Power BI not summing up numerical columns
I have a PowerBI data set which has a lot of numerical(decimal) columns. They used to be perfect until today I downloaded the file from service and I am not able to add all those decimal column for summarization. Although the data type of the columns is still decimal the summmariztion symbol in the visualization data pane is also not available. Even in Power Query the data type is decimal

Can you please open the table in Power Query and provide the data type of the column?

@NickA in Power Query the data type is decimal, updated the screenshot in the question

Why not just create a measure the "hard" way?
MeasureName:=SUM('table'[Column])
If your column isn't numeric, it should throw an error

Implicit measures have been disabled (usually a result of using calculation groups from Tabular Editor)
